# Jenkins nodejs pulgin long running running pm2 deamons

Tags: node.js, jenkins, continuous-integration, pm2

At the end of my Jenkins build I use the nodejs plugin to kick off pm2 to spawn a few deamons. When the build finishes I get the message:

**Process leaked file descriptors. See http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build for more information**

Looking at this, and the corrosponding https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller it suggests that I can run something like:

**BUILD_ID=dontKillMe pm2 start processes.json**

But the deamons are not running after the build completes. Any ideas?

Thanks, Chris

Comment: have you found an answer to this?

Comment: it works for me with `BUILD_ID=dontKillMe pm2 restart server.js`. I get  a process: 9054 ?        Ssl    0:01 node /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/BGE/server.js